# Is it possible to create multi-record custom fields on Activities?

Tags: activities

Has anyone found a way to create multi-record custom fields on Activities? We have an example where a single activity can contain multiple funding sources and need to be able to enter them into the one activity

Comment: some work has started at https://lab.civicrm.org/partners/ixiam/com.ixiam.modules.multivalueactivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently.

In general, feature requests like this can be handled in a few ways:

- If you are a developer, you can submit a pull-request with the new feature.
- If you have funds to contribute, you can submit a feature-request to the [paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue) for the core team to work on.
- You can work around your problem using existing features. For example you could set up the custom field as a "Note" textarea and put the multiple funding sources each on a separate line of the same field.

Comment: thanks for your help, will consider best way to approach feature request, assume that other users out there will have similar requests, in meantime thanks for the Notes solution which will at least allow us to capture the data in the right place.